# Sum of infinite sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone explain how to calculate the value of this sequence?
$.5 - \dfrac{.5^2}{2} + \dfrac{.5^3}{3} - \dfrac{.5^4}{4} + \dfrac{.5^5}{5} -...$
I would think I could use the sigma function on a calculator if it didn't alternate adding and subtracting the terms. Would there be a way to get around that?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)= x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - ...$

Then your sum is $f(0.5)$. To solve it take the derivative

$df/dx = 1 - x + x^2 - ... = 1/(1+x)$

Integrate up

$f(x) = \log(1+x)$

where we have used $f(0) = 0$. This gives us $f(0.5) = \log(3/2)$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\ln (1 + x) = x - \dfrac{x^2}{2} + \dfrac{x^3}{3} - \dfrac{x^4}{4}\dots$, your series is equivalent to $\ln 1.5 = \ln 3 - \ln 2 \approx 0.4054651081081645$.

It's an [alternating harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Alternating_harmonic_series)